# Software design: how to get DLL version number

Tags: windows

I have a DLL used in a compliance scenario (the details of which are irrelevant).  The important point is that the main executeable must display the DLL version number.  My solution was that the DLL has a function to return it's own version - ie obtain it from the its own version resource and return it as a string.

My reviewer says that the main program should work out the DLL version number.  He even gave me some code to get the DLL module handle and extract the version using that.

My question is, which is a better design and why?  My feeling is that, using OO principles, I should ask the DLL for its version number.  Doing it the other way means that the main program needs to know how the version information is stored and is hence more tightly coupled to the implementation.

Note that I know exactly how to extract the version information from a DLL.  My question is about the best place for the code that does this.

Comment: The answer depends on the details (so they *are* relevant). Given the information presented here, I can argue both cases in good conscience. (Also I suspect that there is no clear-cut answer and it's just a matter of a design decision.)

Comment: I think either approach is fine, though GetFileVersionInfo() is generic and can work with any DLL.  The only catch is that you need to ensure the version information is accurate; ideally this should be automated by your build system.

Comment: Making each DLL responsible for reporting its own version means that the same code is duplicated in every DLL, which violates DRY. Since version stamping is standardized, there's no real benefit to encapsulation here unless you intend to change to a nonstandard version stamping scheme in the future.

Comment: Holy Cow! Real Raymond Chen in the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you clarify the environment that you're working in? For now, since you've already mentioned getting the module handle, I'll assume you're using C++ and calling one of a handful of Win32 functions (GetModuleHandle, LoadLibrary etc).

First of all, I'd be careful about applying OO principles in too wide a context. The object oriented paradigm helps you structure your software in a more maintainable and understandable way, the problem you're describing sounds like it maybe stretches outside of the boundaries of your application. If you want to get information about a separate resource, such as a DLL, you should consider using a standard approach to achieving this to ensure that your code is decoupled from the items that it needs to inspect.

If you introduce a function into the DLL to return the version number to your main application, you have created a tight coupling between your main application and any DLL that needs to supply it's version information (by essentially defining a bespoke API or interface for this).

You should consider using standard, platform-wide functionality to retrieve the information instead This will allow your application to version any DLL for which it can obtain a handle.

Assuming you have an HMODULE for the dll (and you're using C++), call the following functions to get the version...

GetModuleFileNameEx (to get the full path and filename of the DLL if you don't already know this)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx

using this filename, call

GetFileVersionInfoSize (look these up on MSDN)

This will tell you some crucial information about the file's version metadata (how much info, if any the file has). Assuming this function succeeds, call

GetFileVersionInfo

This will load all the file info metadata into a buffer, then call

VerQueryValue

Supply '\' as the lpSubBlock  parameter to get the standard file info metadata (including the version number)

The above functions will allow you to write code to get the version number of any module that your code can get a handle to.

Of course, if you're using C# the solution is much simpler. Hope this helps...